# How does nSequence/Check Sequence Verify work?

Tags: locktime, bip

How does relative timelock work? I mean, I know the theoretical description, but how to use nSequence concretely ? Can you do me a practical example with 2 sample transactions one of which locked with nSequence from another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use a relative time lock, you need to provide the requirements in the `scriptPubKey` to which the Bitcoin is sent.

### Example

`scriptPubKey` for escrow with 30 day timeout:

```
IF
    2 <Alice's pubkey> <Bob's pubkey> <Escrow's pubkey> 3 CHECKMULTISIG
ELSE
    "30d" CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY DROP
    <Alice's pubkey> CHECKSIG
ENDIF
```

Then, in order to spend it before 30 days, the `scriptSig` that satisfies the first conditional statement (multisig script) must be provided, i.e.:

`scriptSig`: `0 <signature1> <signature2>`

Or after 30 days, alice can provide:

`scriptSig`: `<signature>`

See [BIP112](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0112.mediawiki#escrow-with-timeout)

### Sequence

Note that in order to set a relative locktime: the tx must have the following properties:

- version must be 2 or greater
- nSequence must not have 32nd bit set
- nSequence must have the 23rd bit set (`0x400000`) if it is a lock-time type, unset for block height type
- for relative lock-time type the granularity of each bit is 512 seconds
- for relative block height type each bit represents 1 block

For 30 days, I believe it would be as follows:

```
30 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 2592000 seconds
2592000 / 512 = 5062.5 ~= 5063 or 0x13C7
sequence = 0x13C7 | 0x400000 = 0x4013C7 or 4199367
nSequence = 0xC7134000 (little endian)
```

The sequence is the last 4 bytes of an input, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

Comment: Thank you, very clear. Do u know where to add nSequence parameter inside a transaction?

Comment: The sequence or locktime is the very last 4 bytes of the transaction, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

Comment: @JBaczuk - Has the impact of little endian encoding been taken into consideration after performing BIP 68 bit encoding?

Comment: @skaht right, you'd need to convert to little endian before putting it in the transaction

Comment: The `nSequence` field is not the same as the `nLockTime` field.  The `nSequence` field is per-input, and inputs can have different values set.  See _General format (inside a block) of each input of a transaction - Txin_ in the bitcoin wiki link.

Comment: Right, thanks I was mixing the two terms, I'll try to clarify

Comment: nSequence is at the TX input level. Was referring to each TX output CSV opcode locktime needing to be BIP 68 encoded and converted to little endian format. nLockTime is associated with absolute time locks.

Comment: TX version number must be set to 2 or greater per https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0112.mediawiki#summary.

Answer (score 1):

I am still having problems understanding the relative locktime:

I am aware that the scriptpubkey is "Time Locked" as mentioned above :

```
   "30d" CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY DROP
    <Alice's pubkey> CHECKSIG
```

So when I want to spend this output, do I actually have to set the nSequence Field by myself. I mean, what prevents me from just calculating the right values which satisfies the OP_Code. I am missing the actual connection to the real transaction, like which procedure checks that this transaction has really been 30 days in the blockchain since it appeared in a block.

To prevent older nodes from forking of, the final nSequence should also be calculated into a resulting locktime, to prevent older nodes form spending it?

Comment: What's crucial to understand is that the redeem script (the script that you quoted here) that is present must match the script hash in the UTXO. The spender does _not_ control the script. 

So the spend dictates the value in CSV(value). And CSV(value) WILL fail if value is less than the nSequence in your input which is trying to spend the UTXO (as specified in BIP-068). So BIP-068 sets a way for inputs to be valid only a relative amount of time, while BIP-112 with CSV makes the unlock script writer able to assert a minimum relative amount of time for the input.